What's the equivalent of python3 -m pip install on modern debian-alikes?
I'm currently trying to do an install of changedetection.io with playwright. I don't want to do the docker install since the rest of my environment is using incus.
The instructions given are for debian 11 - and indicate you should do.
python3 -m pip install playwright - else you get an error in changedetection that says  "No module named 'playwright'". This command works fine in Debian 11, and with some changes I get the software running successfully.
I'd like to use a newer version of Debian (12) or Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, since the current builds of changedetection.io require a newer Python version (3.10), and I need to make a few changes on the instructions anyway:
However doing this in either of the newer OSes gives me this error
eek@shitbox:~$ python3 -m pip install playwright
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
    python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.

    If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
    create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
    Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
    sure you have python3-full installed.

    If you wish to install a non-Debian packaged Python application,
    it may be easiest to use pipx install xyz, which will manage a
    virtual environment for you. Make sure you have pipx installed.

    See /usr/share/doc/python3.12/README.venv for more information.

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.

In this case, using pipx results in the error mentioned about module not found inside the changedetection.io app as mentioned in the guide, so I'm running --break-system-packages ,
What's the 'correct' way to install something from pip/pipx as a module with modern Debian based systems?

Please provide the exact error message you get with pipx. I only used it once thus far, but it worked for me. // Also, why not just explicitly use a venv?

There's no errors in pipx - the errors are in the  changedetection.io app itself - I get an error " "No module named 'playwright'"" when I try to configure changedetection to use the chrome page webscraping. I'll try to update with a screenshot - but I'd guess its not finding wherever playwright is. Its a 'known' issue mentioned in the instructions

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76641565/3720510

I believe that Python 3.12 explicitly tries to protect system packages at all costs.
Even if that cost is breaking previously accepted — and expected — pip3 behavior.
Note: This answer is based in my experiences using Python 3.12 installed via Homebrew on macOS Sonoma (14.5). But I think the experience is akin to issues with Python 3.12, in general, regardless of being installed on Debian, Ubuntu or macOS.

I think the solution to make it behave the old way is to use the --break-system-packages flag like this:
pip3 install --break-system-packages playwright

That pipx causes more headaches because while it gently informs the user that pipx should be used instead of local user installs, it is vague in its actual functionality and use. That error message assumes that you fully understand what pipx does and it doesn’t address users who just want to install something via pip3 and are not well versed in Python/pip3 quirk.

I'm doing this now and since its a container, I don't particularly care if anything breaks.   It just seems like wierd advice - and maybe I'm in the wierd place where I'm a poweruser who's not a dev
